# Detect Headphones through Ionic

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, ionic-framework

I was wondering if there was any way to detect whether or not headphones are plugged in to a mobile device (in this case an iPhone) through Ionic. Our Ionic app plays sound, which sounds fine without headphones, but has some wonky results when headphones are plugged in.

If you start the app without headphones, then plug them in, the app constantly buzzes. If you start the app after plugging headphones in, it sounds fine, but then if you unplug the headphones, the sound will not play from the speakers, though the app thinks the sound is playing. It's all very weird. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this plug in :
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/HeadsetDetection-PhoneGap-Plugin

If you want to check at the startup, you can place it inside `$ionicPlatform.ready` like this:

```
window.plugins.headsetdetection.detect(function (detected) {
            alert("Headphone " + detected)
})
```

Else if you want to check on any button click or on function you can make it like this:

HTML:

```
<button class="button button-stable" ng-click="checkHeadphone()">
```

JS:

```
$scope.checkHeadphone = function () {
        window.plugins.headsetdetection.detect(function (detected) {
            alert("Headphone " + detected)
        })
    }
```

So on click of the button it will check if headphone is detected

**Note**: please build/prepare the code for the platform after you install plugin if you still getting error of 'undefined'

This should work for iOS or Android

Comment: How can I actually get this to work with ionic? I have installed the plugin, but when I try the code above, it give this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'detect' of undefined

Comment: Hi @BenjaminMathers, you can use as following:
declare var HeadsetDetection: any;  //declare this in scope of file and
HeadsetDetection.detect(function (detected) { } })  //use this to detect Headset